# How to send a 2-D array as a reference in C++, and back?

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

yet another beginner-to-intermediate question. I'm trying to pass a 2-D array to a function in C++. I'm aware that the array can't be sent directly to the function, so I first created a pointer (names edited but you'll get the idea):

```
double input[a][b] = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}};
Class.calculate (*(input), a, b);
```

Then I try to use it in said function - but seemingly I'm unaware on how to dereference the pointer to be able to handle the 2-D array again. My code (more or less):

```
for (int x=0; x<=a; x++){
    for (int y=0; y<=b; y++){
        tmpInput[x][y]= (*input)[x][y];
    }
}
```

The compiler complains about an error, namely `invalid types ‘double[int]’ for array subscript`, but I still can't figure out the problem. My best bet is that I didn't dereference the 2-D array properly, but the other option is that C++ can't dereference 2-D arrays directly, instead relying in converting the array to 1-D before sending it. Any ideas?

Comment: Of COURSE you can "send an array to a function".  Just declare it as "**double" (as littleadv suggested) or, equivalently, as "*double[]" (as Mahesh suggested).

Comment: @paulsm4: I tried with @littleadv's suggestion, and declared `calculate(double** input, int a, int b)`, calling it with `Class.calculate(input, a, b);`. It didn't work: `error: no matching function for call to ‘Class::calculate(float [(((unsigned int)(((int)a) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)][(((unsigned int)(((int)b) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)], int&, int&)’`

Comment: You probably want `x < a` instead of `x <= a` (same for `y` and `b`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure without seeing the declaration of `calculate()`, but I'd guess it's an argument type mismatch.  You can send your array as a `double*`, but not as a `double**` - it *is* an array of doubles (they're laid out linearly in memory, even if the compiler lets you treat them as a multidimensional array).  But it is *not* an array of pointers to doubles, which is what the `double**` type actually means:  Dereference a `double**` and you get a `double*`.

If you know that the second subscript is constant (in your case, 2), you can define `calculate()` to expect a N*2 array of doubles:

```
void calculate(double array[][2], int a)
{
    //Whatever
}
```

Or, if both dimensions can change, just take a straight `double*` and to the pointer math yourself (you'll probably have to cast your array to a `double*` when calling this, but it'll work):

```
void calculate(double* array, int a, int b)
{
    //To get array[i][j]:
    array[i * b + j];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It nearly worked! Unfortunately there's an error: when I try to send the array, instead of being treated as a `float*` (sorry, changed type since sending the question), it's treated as a `float [(((unsigned int)(((int)xMax) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)][(((unsigned int)(((int)h) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)]` (insert a "lolwut" here)

Comment: @Carlos - I've looked around for ways to do this, but there just aren't any good ones.  the second post in [this thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/11627/) sums it up pretty well - you've got three options, and none of them are quite what you're looking for:  1) Know your dimensions beforehand.  2) Explicitly cast to a float* when you call the function.  3) Use a "pointer to pointer to float (float**)" setup.  Or see if you can reorganize your code and use a one-dimensional array and save yourself a lot of headaches.  Cheers!

Comment: What I did was to refactor the 2-D array into a 1-D array; since I already passed the maximum size for both dimensions, creating a `float[a*x+b]` was easy... Or was it `float[b*x+a]`?

Answer (score 3):

Why the array cannot be sent directly to a function?

Call `Class.calculate (*(input), a, b);` is trying to dereference `input` which you can't do as it is not a pointer.

If the `calculate` is defined as:

```
Class::calculate(double *input[], size a, size b)
```

You can just call `Class.calculate(input, a, b)`.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm aware that the array can't be sent directly to the function, so I first created a pointer (names edited but you'll get the idea)

Wrong. You can pass it. Just have the `calculate` member function's first argument to be pointer to a pointer.

```
calculate( double **ptr, int rows, int columns ){

   // Now access the array via ptr as usual with the [] operator. 
   // like ptr[0][1]
}
```

And call it like - Class.calculate (input, a, b);

Comment: Ookay... But, how do I send the parameter, as `Class.calculate (*(input), a, b);` or as `Class.calculate (input, a, b);` ?

Comment: As `Class.calculate(input, a, b);` because two dimensional array decays to a pointer to a pointer. Strictly speaking pointer to the first row.

Answer (score 2):

No one said anything about templates yet? I'm disappointed!

---

You can actually pass it as a real reference without the need to pass the size as extra parameters in C++:

```
class Class{
public:
  // ...
  template<unsigned N, unsigned M>
  void calculate(double (&arr)[N][M]){
    // use it like normal, arr[x][y]
    // ...
  }
  // ...
};
```

[Example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/dsqHY)

Even though this doesn't answer the exact question you asked, it's always good to know such stuff. :) Templates are an important part of C++ after all, no matter if you're beginner, intermediate or a pro. You use them, though maybe not knowingly, from day 1.

Comment: For the record, the code for my class is (more or less) posted at http://ideone.com/LZiAY (thanks for suggesting Ideone!). And sorry, no time to learn templates, I have only three days to learn WxWidgets and file manipulation before handing out this work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Boost.MultiArray:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

they support views, ranges, iterators and they abstract away memory management but still remain extremely configurable.  You can pass multi_arrays by reference just like you'd expect.

if you want to learn about raw pointers (or you're writing an embedded application that needs to fit in 64k of memory or something), then it's a good idea write code that uses them.  If you want to write maintainable production code, then it's a good idea to use STL/Boost and avoid raw pointers except in code that is unlikely to have to be read very much.